# Objective-c. How can I generate the same token based on 2 user ids no matter which is first

Tags: objective-c, xcode, nsstring, token

I'm using objective-c
Say I have 2 user ids
"10000000000" and "10000000001". 
how can I create a value that will be exactly the same no matter which is first. 
My initial thought was to cast the NSStrings to an int. 
so 10000000000+10000000001 would always be 20000000001. Then cast that back to NSString. But I'm getting strange results. The value always comes out as 5 or 10. I've also tried this with long long.

one of the ids could potentially look like this 5Uc0vFgVCvd3WL0Q18yevthTe

Is there a way to generate a token based on 2 strings that is the same for no matter which is first?

Comment: I'm really curious to know how you get 5 or 10 as a result. Are you running this on OSX or on iOS?

Comment: You could always just sort the two values and then concatenate them together.

Comment: I'm developing for ios.

Comment: Addition will do what you need here, as would _any other_ commutative operator (bitwise XOR, e.g.), unless you have other requirements. If you're getting weird results with your specific addition code, you need to post that code. Interesting task, but it's not really clear what the problem is that you need solved -- you seem to already have solved it except perhaps for the implementation.

Answer (score 3):

I'd recommend hashing each NSString and adding the hashcodes together
like:

```
NSString* user1 = @"100000000";
NSString* user2 = @"198231498";

NSUInteger token = user1.hash + user2.hash;
```

You could convert that to a string with:

```
NSString* tokenString = [NSString stringwithFormat:@"%u",token];
```

Comment: Except that hash codes are not guaranteed to be unique.

Comment: It wasn't a requirement for the resulting token to be guaranteed unique, just that it was the same no matter the order of the 2 user ids. Adding them together isn't guaranteed either (even if it worked)